# Extracting columns from different csv files into a single file

Tags: python, file, csv

Could someone please help me with this problem? I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I have 10 different csv files. Each file contains varying number of columns. Each column contains a header and data. I want to copy selective columns from different csv files and lay them out in a particular order in a new file. For example, columns 1,5,6 from file1, columns 1,2,3 from file 2, columns 8 from file3 to create a file containing 7 columns in the respective format:

```
column1(file1)  column1(file2) column2(file2) column3(file2) column5(file1) column8(file3) column6(file1)
```

How do I code this?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but should put you on the right path:

```
import csv
import itertools

FILES = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', ...]

with open('output', 'wb') as output:
    input_files = [ csv.reader(open(fname, 'rb')) for fname in FILES ]
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in itertools.izip(*input_files):
        writer.writerow([
            # format is row[file#-1][column#-1]
            row[0][0],
            row[1][0],
            row[1][1],
            row[1][2],
            row[0][4],
            row[2][7],
            row[0][5],
        ])
```

Comment: I just tried it and encountered this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/choosing_columns.py", line 13, in <module>
    writer.writerow([row[0][0],row[1][0], row[2][0]])
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Any advice on a way forward would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: The only way you'd be seeing that error is if you're doing `for row in input_files`. The `izip` is very important: it produces a `tuple` that that consists of one row from each file at the same time. Please note that I've updated my solution to fix an unrelated error: I wasn't using zero indexing.